# What protocol does SAP HANA studio use in order to communicate with a HANA database?

Tags: hana

I would just like to know how HANA Studio communicates with a HANA DB? What kind of protocol does it use? Does it use JDBC or SQLDBC?

Answer (score 2):

SAP HANA Studio uses JDBC for the majority of all communication with a SAP HANA server. 
Features like the `sapstartsrvc` connection for starting/stopping the system or the landscape management use http-based protocols.